# play framework 2.4.2 client connection remains open

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-activator, playframework-2.4

i am using using activator project which has play 2.4.2 . just for testing i deployed raw project which only listen on port 80 0r 9000 and returning Ok("abc"). 
but when i check the output of 
    $ sudo lsof -i | wc -l
the number increasing gradually with time, and after some time let say 24-48 hours. the server crashes with exception too many file open.

i tested with apache benchmark also, after completion of benchmarking, there is still some connections open and never close.

please someone help.

Comment: If your test case is as simple as you say, you should submit a bug on github https://github.com/playframework/playframework

Comment: Better to ask on the [user MailingList](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/play-framework). The github tracker is for confirmed issue.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some debate around this issue, when sometime back I was working with playframework.

First verify that if your client is asking for connection to be kept alive. In this case playframework would honor the client and keep the connection open. [See this disscussion](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1103) . The takeaway from discussion was play can handle a lot of request, which is questionable if you think about DoS attacks.

The other thing there seems to be options to kill the connection from the action with the header, but I have never tried with those. See [this](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1118). I am not able to pull any documentation around this option at this moment.
Edit : Seems to be mentioned in [2.2. hightlight](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Highlights22).

Comment: Thanks @Biswanath . i think this is very much helpful.